# Add Contour Curve to Scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am trying to include a rotated parabola on a scatter plot using ggplot.  I am able to plot the dataframe and differentiate between the classes, but when I go to plot the boundary curve, which I have here called 'para', I get "object 'category' not found".
Also, when I plot the curve separately, I get the curve.  It is when I attempt to add the contour.

What am I missing?

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(-0.674, -1.579, 2.272, 0.974,1.323, -3.953, 1.08, 3.85, 3.543, 0.385),
  y = c(2.771, -0.812, -0.166, -1.489, -2.618, -0.755, 3.5, -1.13, 2.472, -0.211),
  category = c(1,  1,  1,  0,1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1))

para <- function(x, y) {
  p <- -.1*x^2 - .3 * y^2 + 0.38 * x * y + 0.22 * x + 0.98 * y - 0.1
  return(p)
}


x_values <- seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length.out = 500)
y_values <- seq(min(df$y), max(df$y), length.out = 500)
grid <- expand.grid(x = x_values, y = y_values)
grid$z <- mapply(para, grid$x, grid$y)


scatter_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(category))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "red", "1" = "blue")) +
  coord_fixed()

contour_plot <- geom_contour(data = grid, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z), breaks = 0, linetype = "solid")

final_plot <- scatter_plot + contour_plot

print(final_plot)
```

Comment: Move the color aesthetic mapping to your points: `geom_point(aes(color = factor(category)))` and remove it from the `ggplot()` function.

Comment: That worked!  Why did that work?

Comment: Hi @gunsnfloyd, by default `geom_contour` is inheriting aesthetics. You are explicitly overriding mappings for `x` and `y`, but not `color`. So it goes looking for the inherited mapping, which is a variable named `category` which happens to not exist in its data. As a 3rd alternative to what I include in my answer, you can add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_contour` and your original code should all work as you expected.

Comment: So I am overriding the mappings in scale_color_manual?

Comment: The issue in the original code is that you are mapping a variable that doesn't exist in the `grid` data frame. You can manage that by either 1) Move `aes(color = category)` to `geom_point`, 2) assign a color in `geom_contour`, or 3) add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_contour`. In all 3 you are not affecting the mapping to your points, so `scale_color_manual` will still work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the `color` aesthetic specifically in `geom_point` will let you add the contour plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(-0.674, -1.579, 2.272, 0.974,1.323, -3.953, 1.08, 3.85, 3.543, 0.385),
  y = c(2.771, -0.812, -0.166, -1.489, -2.618, -0.755, 3.5, -1.13, 2.472, -0.211),
  category = c(1,  1,  1,  0,1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1))

para <- function(x, y) {
  p <- -.1*x^2 - .3 * y^2 + 0.38 * x * y + 0.22 * x + 0.98 * y - 0.1
  return(p)
}

x_values <- seq(min(df$x), max(df$x), length.out = 500)
y_values <- seq(min(df$y), max(df$y), length.out = 500)
grid <- expand.grid(x = x_values, y = y_values)
grid$z <- mapply(para, grid$x, grid$y)

scatter_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(category))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "red", "1" = "blue")) +
  coord_fixed()

contour_plot <- geom_contour(data = grid,
               aes(x = x, y = y, z = z),
               breaks = 0, linetype = "solid")

scatter_plot + contour_plot
```

[image]

Alternatively, map `color` in the `ggplot` function, and specifically assign a color to the contour:

```r
scatter_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(category))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "red", "1" = "blue")) +
  coord_fixed()

contour_plot <- geom_contour(data = grid,
               aes(x = x, y = y, z = z), color = 'orange',
               breaks = 0, linetype = "solid")

scatter_plot + contour_plot
```

[image]